# Update Dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to inset new key,value pair into a variable that was not previously defined

Here is what i want to do:

```
def drawboard(nextmove):
    result = nextmove

    pos = 1
    print result

    for i in range(7):
        for j in range(7):
            if (j == 0 or i % 2 == 0 or j % 2 == 0):
                print '*',
            if (i % 2 != 0 and j % 2 != 0):
                print pos,
                pos += 1
            if (j == 6):
                print '\n'
    move = raw_input("Input you move(i.e. x,3[position, your symbol]: ")
    if move == 'q':
        exit()

    calcres(move)


def calcres(move):
    nextmove = dict([move.split(',')])
    drawboard(nextmove)


drawboard({0: 0})
```

Inside `drawboard` function i want to concatenate `nextmove` with result, and save all the moves inside the result finally. I tried initializing `result = {}` but as expected that removes all items from result and re-initializes it resulting only one item inside that dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setdefault` to initialize the `result` dictionary value to an empty list whenever the key is not present

```
def drawboard(nextmove):

    result.setdefault(nextmove[0],[]).append(nextmove[1])
    pos = 1
    #print result

    for i in range(7):
        for j in range(7):
            if (j == 0 or i % 2 == 0 or j % 2 == 0):
                print '*',
            if (i % 2 != 0 and j % 2 != 0):
                print pos,
                pos += 1
            if (j == 6):
                print '\n'
    move = raw_input("Input you move(i.e. x,3[position, your symbol]: ")
    if move == 'q':
        exit()

    calcres(move)


def calcres(move):
    nextmove = move.split(',')
    drawboard(nextmove)

result = {}
drawboard([0,0])
```